# Keeping best entry in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

Assuming I have the following dataframe:

```
    DeedNo  Partner1    Partner2
0   4       Ysolda      Calcerani
2   4       Calcerani   
3   4                   Ysolda
4   4       Calcerano   Ysolda
5   4       Calceranus  Ysolde
6   10      Catherina
7   10      Lencium     
8   10      Lencij  
9   18      Catherina   Frankynj
10  18                  Frankyni Vassaldo
```

Is there a way to keep the best entry per deed ie: for deed 4 the best entries can be either (Ysolda, Calcerani), (Calcerano, Ysolda) or (Calceranus, Ysolde)

For deed 10 (Catherina) and (Lencium or Lenciy) are the best while for deed 18 (Catherina, Frankynj) are the best.

I am trying to get married couples from text but as you can see there are name variants and sometimes it is possible to get only one of the partners although the keyword for the relationship is present. Thankyou

Comment: Define "best" and possibly show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: How can you get *the best* entry if it is not unique? For rows with missing entries use `dropna(how='any', axis=0)`.

Comment: I am defining best as an entry of a couple ex: Ysolda, Calcerani is a couple and there are variants of it that I don't need. One is enough. When there is only one partner of the couple I want to keep it if there is not the full entry of the couple